# How to sum a sub-tensor of high dimention tensor in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector, multidimensional-array

We are given a D-dimensional tensor, represented as a vector of size n^D.

The vector represents a D-dimensional distribution of a random variable X \in  {0,1,..,n}^d. That is the (i_1,i_2,...,i_d) entry in the tensor represents the probability of X_1 = i_1, X_2 = i_2, ... X_d = i_d.

I need to compute, for each dimension d, and value i\in [n] the marginal distribution P(X_d = i).

i.e., this means that the answer of P(X_d = i) is the sum of n^(D-1) entries of the vector.

For example, if D=2 and n=4, we have a vector x of size (16,1) and the probability of the first dimension being equal to 1 is

> P(X_1 = 1) = x(1) + x(2) + x(3) + x(4)

The probability of the second dimension being equal to 3 is '

> P(X_2 = 3) = x(3) + x(7) + x(11) + x(15)

I'm writing Matlab code that needs to compute these marginal distributions, but I'm not familiar enough with Matlab to do it in a simple way (it is doable using some ugly recursion, but there has to be a better option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate `P(X_k=z)` for a `D`-dimensional matrix you can use

```
xD = reshape(x, n*ones(1,D)); 
B = permute(xD, [k setdiff(1:D, k)]);
P = sum(B(z,:));
```

It first makes it a `D`-dimensional matrix. It brings the dimension of interest `k` to the beginning and then chooses the `z`-th element and sums over elements corresponding to that.

Answer (score 0):

[Mohsen Nosratinia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26144658/2586922) would be my first option. As an alternative, it can be done without reshaping or permuting dimensions, which can result in faster code:

```
k = 2; %// chosen dimension
z = 3; %// chosen value (along d-th dimension)
result = sum(x(mod(floor((0:end-1)/n^(k-1)), n)==z-1));
```